# Choosing a destination drive

Tags: mac-mini

I have dual drives in my mac mini(late 2012). I would like to install certain programs only on the drive of my choice. How can I do it? I am new to the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

- If the program is available as a .pkg file, that is, an installer package, you can choose <kbd>Change Install Location...</kbd>:

  [image]

  and choose another disk:

  [image]
- You can also drag and drop installed apps in `/Applications` to another drive of your choice.
- If you compile a program, you can choose a destination directory in another drive when running `./configure`.

The methods mentioned above are safe, but note that some programs won't run if forced to install in another locations, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84270/how-to-install-framework-from-pkg-file-in-a-non-standard-location/84275#84275 for such an example.